# Which loss function to use in an anomaly detection autoencoder and which output shape to choose?

Tags: python, autoencoder, loss-function, anomaly-detection

I am trying to build an autoencoder model for anomaly detection in Python. My label (anomaly_label) is either 0 (normal) or 1 (abnormal). I am trying to understand which loss function to use; if I am not wrong, since I have only two values and my label is not one-hot encoded (integer column), then it is better to choose either: 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' or 'binary_crossentropy'. Am I right?

My second question is about the output layer size, when I use 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy' I set it to the number of classes (2 in this case), but when I use 'binary_crossentropy' I set it to 1. Is it correct?

The following is my model architecture:

```
def get_autoencoder(loss_func):

    out_size = 0
    num_classes = 2
    if loss_func == 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy':
        out_size = num_classes
    if loss_func == 'binary_crossentropy':
        out_size = 1

    # input layer
    inp = Input(shape=(78,)) # layer 1
    
    # encoding layers
    enc = Dense(512)(inp) # layer 2
    enc = Dropout(0.5)(enc)
    enc = LeakyReLU(0.01)(enc)
    enc = Dense(256)(enc) # layer 3
    enc = Dropout(0.5)(enc)
    enc = LeakyReLU(0.01)(enc)
    enc = Dense(128)(enc) # layer 4
    enc = Dropout(0.5)(enc)
    enc = LeakyReLU(0.01)(enc)
    
    # bottleneck layer
    mid = Dense(64)(enc) # layer 5
    mid = Dropout(0.5)(mid)
    mid = LeakyReLU(0.01)(mid)
    
    # decoding layers
    dec = Dense(128)(mid) # layer 6
    dec = Dropout(0.5)(dec)
    dec = LeakyReLU(0.01)(dec)
    dec = Dense(256)(dec) # layer 7
    dec = Dropout(0.5)(dec)
    dec = LeakyReLU(0.01)(dec)
    dec = Dense(512)(dec) # layer 8
    dec = Dropout(0.5)(dec)
    dec = LeakyReLU(0.01)(dec)
    
    # output layer
    out = Dense(out_size, activation='sigmoid')(dec)
    
    # create new model
    autoencoder = Model(inp, out)
    autoencoder.compile(loss=loss_func, optimizer='rmsprop')
    return autoencoder
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand what I am doing is right or wrong, and if the latter, how to correct my model? Thanks.

Comment: If you have labeled data for anomaly/normal for training, then you should use a regular classification model - not an autoencoder. Autoencoders are for unsupervised learning, where there are no labels for training (or at least not enough of them).

Comment: Thanks. I will investigate more, but when I train my Autoencoder, I give it as training input all the features (X) that are normal (0), then when I apply it on the testing data, I get the reconstruction error and then I try to find the optimal threshold that gives the best accuracy metrics values (accuracy, f1_score, precision, recall). Is it wrong?

Comment: That setup is correct for unsupervised learning with autoencoder. But in that case the output of your model should have the same dimensions as the input. And your targets should be then input data. And you should use a loss like MSE

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no information about your input data this is just a guess:
you want to detect anomalies in a signal (?) - if so take a look at [Tensorflow Autoencoder Intro](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder). They describe anomaly detection in ECG using an autoencoder.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33652457)

Comment: @Daraan Since the asker wanted to know how to correct the model - and this needs correction since an autoencoder doesn't work like that- there is a link in the answer to do what the asker wants. This is the help that's possible with the provided information.